# How to use std::variant type with %type directive

Tags: c++, bison, flex-lexer, bisonc++

I am trying to write some grammar in bison that parses C Code. I am new to bison and I am trying to learn from examples that I find online. I am in the process of writing AST. If this is the grammar that I define (most basic use case)

```
declarator
: IDENTIFIER         { $$ = $1;}
| declarator '(' ')' { $$ = new functionDecl($1); }
```

Now when I compile this code, an error message is thrown that 'declarator' does not have a type.

I understand that I can define the type using %type declarative. But I want "declarator" to be associated with a variant type:

```
%code {

class Stmt 
{
   public:
     std::string id;
     Stmt(std::string aId)
     : id(aId)
     {}  
};
typedef std::variant<std::string, Stmt> decl_type;
}

%define api.value.type variant
%token <std::string> IDENTIFIER
%type <decl_type> declarator
```

I am unable to compile this code as well. It throws an error that decl_type is unknown. What am I missing?

Comment: I guess you dont have a default constructor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you write

```
%define api.value.type variant
```

you are telling bison to implement semantic values with *its own implementation of a variant type*.

This is highlighted in the [bison manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html#C_002b_002b-Variants) in a note prominently marked **Warning:**:

> **Warning:** We do not use `Boost.Variant`, for two reasons. First, it appeared unacceptable to require `Boost` on the user’s machine (i.e., the machine on which the generated parser will be compiled, not the machine on which bison was run). Second, for each possible semantic value, `Boost.Variant` not only stores the value, but also a tag specifying its type. But the parser already “knows” the type of the semantic value, so that would be duplicating the information.
>
> We do not use C++17’s `std::variant` either: we want to support all the C++ standards, and of course `std::variant` also stores a tag to record the current type.

(It's worth reading the entire section on Bison variants if you want to use them.)

You could define bison's semantic type to be a `std::variant`, of course:

```
%define api.value.type std::variant<std::string, Stmt>
```

But that might not be what you want, because bison doesn't know anything about `std::variant` and it will not do anything to help you with the syntax of accessing the value of the variant. Normally, as the page on Bison variants points out, Bison can *deduce* the type of the semantic value of a grammar symbol (using your `%type` declarations, of course), but if you don't use a `union` or Bison variant type, then all Bison knows is that the value is a `std::variant`. If you happen to know that it is a particular type (for example, because you know what the types of your terminal symbols are), and you want to examine the value using that type, you'll have to use `std::variant::get`, something like `$2.get<NodeList>`.

There has been some discussion on the Bison mailing list about improving Bison's handling of variant types. Sadly, I haven't been following it in detail, so you might want to take a look yourself.